# How to clear the session ID of another platform in google data studio community Connector

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I created a community connector for Google Data Studio to get access for another platform. And I want to clear the session ID after getting the data from that platform. What should I do?
Here is my code

```
function fetchFromNodeRestApi(){

  var sessionID = [  
     
    'http://test.smartapps.lk/rest/api/login?loginName=+loginName+&password=+password+'
  ].join(''); 
  
  var responseID = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sessionID);
  var document = XmlService.parse(responseID.getContentText()); 
  var correctSessionId = document.getRootElement().getChild('sessionId').getValue(); 

  var url=[
    'http://test.smartapps.lk/rest/api/selectQuery?sessionId=' + correctSessionId + '&maxRows=5&query=select Item_Name, Date , Weight from Customer_Order_demand &output=json'
  ].join('');
  
  var responseID2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); 

  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(responseID2.getContentText());  
  
  var finalArray = [];
  
  for(var i in jsonObj){

    var newObj = {
      
      "Item_Name": jsonObj[i][0],
      "Date": jsonObj[i][1],
      "Weight": jsonObj[i][2] 
      
    };
    
    finalArray.push(newObj);
  }   
 return finalArray;     
}
```

Comment: 1) Where do you want to clear the session id from? 2) From your code, it seems like the id is generated at the third party system. In that case, this has nothing to do with Data Studio. This is more about how that third party system operates.

Comment: I'm new to google apps script. I want to clear the session ID after pushing the data into finalArray. Can you suggest a part of code for logout